# Can't connect to my Samba server

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, samba

I can't seem to connect to my Samba server on my Mac anymore. It used to work perfectly fine, but I recently changed my internet service provider and I think that may be an issue. I say that because when I am at university and use the internet connection over there, it works absolutely fine. But on my home connection which was recently changed, I cannot connect as it says "can't find the server". I'm running Snow Leopard.

Could the router be an issue?

edit: I should note that I'm connecting by going to 'Go' > 'Connect to Server'. Basically trying to map a network drive.